# Javascript Tabs - How to add hashtags on URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

My Tabs works fine, but I need to have a separate function which directs with a URL to the tab, so I can have a separate link for each tab.

How Can I achieve that?

> url.com/#tab1
>
> url.com/#tab2

I tried many ways but I keep getting undefined hashtag. I'd like advice please, I put together a demo, which shows the full working experience.

```js
var boxLink = $( '.but' );
var box = $( '.tab' );

boxLink.click( function() {
 $('#but1').removeClass('active');
 
    var boxID = $(this).attr("data-target");
    var currentbox = $('.tab:not(.is-hidden)');
    var targetBox = $('.tab#' + boxID);
    
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active'))    {
        boxLink.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        TweenMax.to( currentbox, 0.2, {ease:Power4.easeOut, className: '-=visible', autoAlpha: 0,  onComplete: boxIn, onCompleteParams: [targetBox] });
    }
    
    return false;
});

var boxIn = function( targetBox ) {
    box.addClass( 'is-hidden' );
    targetBox.removeClass( 'is-hidden' );
    
    TweenMax.to( targetBox, 0.2, {autoAlpha: 1,className: '+=visible', ease:Power4.easeIn});
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
 }
#tab01 {
background: white;
}

#tab02 {
background: red;
} 
 
.tab {
width:100px;
height:100px;
font-size:30px;
line-height:100px;
text-align:center;
}
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
} 

button {
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab" id="tab01">one</div>
<div class="tab is-hidden" id="tab02">two</div>

<button  class="but active" id="but1" data-target="tab01">slide 1</button>
<button  class="but" id="but2" data-target="tab02">slide 2</button>
```

Comment: Do you just want to add #divId in the URL? Or something else?

Comment: I need to navigate with the url direct to the specific tab.
Like: google.com/#tab2, so the tab2 will be active. perhaps another more semantic name. Like title of the page name

Comment: @Bharat Bhushan would you be able to help?

Comment: Sorry, buddy I off my work yesterday. If you didn't find the solution, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you want to show a specific tab on load in case a hash has been added to the page's URL, right? If so you should parse `window.location.href` and check for a hash tag in the URL. If it is present, the hash value e.g. '#tab2' should show the container with the same ID.

**Updated code:**

```js
var currentUrl= window.location.href;
if (currentUrl.indexOf('#') > -1) {
  var hashTag= currentUrl.substring(currentUrl.indexOf('#')+1);
  var targetBox = $('.tab#' + hashTag);
  TweenMax.to( currentbox, 0.2, {ease:Power4.easeOut, 
    className: '-=visible', autoAlpha: 0,  onComplete: boxIn, onCompleteParams: [targetBox] });

  // added: highlight the proper buttons and remove the default "active" element
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.' + hashTag + '-control').addClass('active');
}
```

To also highlight the buttons, you need to give them a class (that's the easiest method as you can't use duplicate IDs so we identify the tab via ID and button via class):

```
<button  class="tab01-control but active" id="but1" data-target="tab01">slide 1</button>
<button  class="tab02-control but" id="but2" data-target="tab02">slide 2</button>
```

Your `boxIn(targetBox)` method expects to receive a jQuery object as "targetBox" parameter and it was a string. Simply append "#tab02" to your URL when you test it locally to have the second tab show up.

**Side note:**

Your Code snippet is currently not working correctly, you should include ...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

... to make your animation work as expected, otherwise you'll receive a JS error message when clicking one of the buttons.

**Edit 1**

As you asked how to use meaningful "hash names" instead of the control's IDs like `tab01`, this can be achieved with a simple switch-case:

```
let hashTag = window.location.hash;
if (hashTag !== '') {
    hashTag = hashTag.substring(1);

    let targetName = '';

    switch (hashTag) {
        case "home":
            targetName = 'tab01';
            break;
        case "profile":
            targetName = 'tab02';
            break;
    }
    if (targetName !== '') {
        var targetBox = $('.tab#' + targetName);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks did you tested? does it work? Would you be able to make a demo? looks like doesn't work

Comment: @user173420 I updated my code sample above, please give it another try. I tested it locally and it works like a charm.

Comment: Go up to your browser url bar and put `#fun` on the end of it.  Now open the developer console and type `window.location.hash`

Comment: @Taplar thank you for that hint, I hadn't known there is `location.hash`!

Comment: @Taplar definitely ;-)

Comment: @SaschaM78 is it possible to make the class active of the button?

Comment: @user173420 have a look at the updated code in my answer.

Comment: @SaschaM78 thank you. ANy reason why I get an error? unrecognized expression: .tab#?

Comment: @user173420 it seems it comes from this line: `var targetBox = $('.tab#' + hashTag);` and hashTag might be blank. Did you pass a hash in the URL when you received that error?

Comment: @SaschaM78 that happens on load

Comment: @user173420 could you add the load routine as an update to your question above? Simply click the "edit" link below the post and then add it on the bottom, best with a short bold text above it like "Updated Code".

Comment: @SaschaM78 hello, sorry to bother you again, do you know why I get this error?
currentbox is not defined ???

Comment: @user173420 No problem. Could be two things: 1.) "currentbox" is a variable that has not been defined yet but you try to access a property of it, i.e. `currentbox.width` or 2.) "currentbox" is created when an external script has been loaded (comparable with `$` that is available as soon as jQuery has been loaded) but in your case the file has not been loaded but again the variable is already accessed before the resource was loaded. HTH!

Comment: @SaschaM78 thanks, it was missing the variable:-) why the ----  $('.' + hashTag + '-control').addClass('active'); this doesn't work, it should add class to active tab

Comment: @user173420 I would recommend to check the contents of the `hashTag` variable and also if the referenced object could be found. Add this in the routine handling the activation of the tab: `console.log(hashTag); console.log($('.' + hashTag + '-control'));`.

Comment: @SaschaM78 thanks that helped! Lastly, do you know how to change the URL on the top? /#box02 or /#box03 or /#box04 to have different names? Like, Nameone, Nametwo, Namethree? without the hash

Comment: @user173420 would it be possible to create a new question with a more detailed description of what you want to achieve? Or do you simply want to use different hash names, i.e. with better names? If that's the case, just make sure that the hash value equals the name of the tab that should be highlighted.

Comment: @SaschaM78 I will ask a new question shortly, but what I need is a different name like NameTwo instead of #tab02. IS it possible?

Comment: @user173420 there are several ways on how to achieve this: either do some mapping between passed variable and desired container to be shown in the JS code or as mentioned before by renaming the container to the passed variable.

Comment: @user173420 have a look at the "Edit 1" section in my answer. [Here's also a demo](http://moonbird.de/tc/sample.html#profile)